# Problem uploading my vexim database

Tags: mysql, linux, exim

Am trying to upload my vexim database but this is the error i get. Anyone with an idea how to solve this? I have tried it with two versions of vexim that is vexim2.2.1.and vexim 2 but i got the same error in both. As below:

```
mysql -u root -p vexim < setup/mysql.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-
-
-
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `vexim`' at line 1**
```

Answer (score 0):

You have something in your `setup/mysql.sql` file that is not clean SQL code. Maybe a stray quote or something?

Comment: thank you. Though wat i changed in setup/mysql.sql file is only the UID and GID.

Comment: You must have made some other subtle change that broke the formatting.